laravel reverb broadcasting/auth 403 error solution in Laravel 11
show 403 forbidden error when use broadcasting/auth for authenticate channel for private or presence channel in laravel 11
I use JWT  for auth API login and add middle wear in broadcast route
in channel.php
Broadcast::routes(
    ['middleware' => [JwtMiddleware::class,CorsMiddelware::class]]
);
Broadcast::channel('chat', function ($user, $id) {
    return true;
});

in JwtMiddleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) :Response
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json(['code' => 401,'message' => 'Token is Invalid']);
            }else if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException){
                return response()->json(['code' => 401,'message' => 'Token is Expired']);
            }else{
                return response()->json(['code' => 401,'message' => 'Authorization Token not found']);
            }
        }

        User::where('id',$user->id)->update(['last_seen_at' => now()]);
        return $next($request);
    }

when hit  /broadcasting/auth
show ERROR status 403

what is that route /broadcasting/auth ?

checkout this youtube video that explains in details laravel web socket and reverb
https://youtu.be/f1xzWRIdw3Y

My issue is that when i pass jwt token in broadcast/auth for authenticate presence and private channel then show 403 forbidden error

Solution already here, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/78580632/21120247
